# Named Chunk build file for VueJS lazy loading routes

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using **vuejs webpack template**. In this I trying to achieve lazy loading. For this, I have written below route-

```
const Setting = resolve => {
    require.ensure(['./components/setting/Setting.vue'], () => {
        resolve(require('./components/setting/Setting.vue'));
    }, 'setting');
};
```

On `npm run build` command, this generates `0.build.js` file as expected. But, I would like generate named chunk file as `setting.build.js` and for other modules like other1.build.js, other2.build.js etc.

Can someone please help me to generate **named chunk file** for each module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by using below in webpack.config.js-

```
  output: {
    ....
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    ....
  },
```

`chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'` generates files with setting.chunk.js and other1.chunk.js and other2.chunk.js etc

`chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'` generates file with 0.chunk.js and 1.chunk.js